# How to use "action" in vb.net using selenium webdriver?

Tags: vb.net, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am using selenium webdriver to automate chrome in VB.net (2019 version).
I want to send some keystrokes to chrome using action. I have tried the following code

```
    Dim driver As IWebDriver
    driver = New ChromeDriver
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com/")
    Dim action1 As Action = New Action(driver)
```

and it is showing me following error at "New action(driver)" location
"Delegate "action: requires as "address of" expression or Lambda expression..."

I have imported the following references

```
Imports SileniumTest
Imports OpenQA.Selenium
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Keys
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions
```

Please let me know what is causing this error?

PS: I have tried using this

```
Dim element As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("userid"))
element2.SendKeys("xyz" & Keys.Enter)
```

This thing works.

But, I want to use actions because I do not have ID of one text box and I want to mimic keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `Action` in that context is being interpreted as the `System.Action` delegate type. If you want to use a different type then you need to qualify the name, e.g.

```vb
Dim action1 As New OpenQA.Selenium.Action(driver)
```

You don't necessarily need the full namespace, if it is a child of another that you have imported. For instance, if that `Action` type is a member of `OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions` and you have imported `OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions`, you can do this:

```vb
Dim action1 As New Actions.Action(driver)
```

Basically, you need to uniquely identify the type so anything that is valid and disambiguates it from `System.Action` will work.